# NGINX - Caching not working - Always MISS

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

I'm currently working on enabling caching on a NGINX (Reverse Proxy).

With this configuration, the value of X-Proxy-Cache is always **MISS**.

My current conf (*in /etc/nginx/conf.d*) :

```
proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache/MON_URL levels=1:2 keys_zone=MY_ZONE:8m max_size=1000m inactive=24h;

upstream opera {
    server MY_SERVER_IP:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MON_URL www.MON_URL;
    return 301 https://MON_URL$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.MON_URL;
    return 301 $scheme://MON_URL$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name MON_URL;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://opera/;
        rewrite ^/$ /OPERA/ last;
        proxy_cache MY_ZONE;
        proxy_cache_valid any 24h;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /";
    }
}
```

I tried different configurations based on the [doc](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) or different posts here, without success.

I hope someone could help me move forward on this problem! Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the Cache-Control header that your application sends back?

Comment: `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate`

`Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store`

Comment: Well, there is your answer. You have explicitly told it not to cache in both cases.

Comment: This is not what I defined in my configuration, right?

Comment: The nginx cache will only cache responses that are cacheable by a shared cache. None of your responses are cacheable.

Comment: So I have to update my configuration so that it caches?

Comment: You have to update your Cache-Control headers so that responses can be cached.

Comment: More explicitly: You need to update the application at `https://opera` to send proper cache headers. Another thing you need to note are cookies. If any response sets cookies, nginx will not cache that response.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, in my case it was this line:

```
proxy_buffering    off;
```

It's also mentioned in the "common mistakes" article on their blog:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#proxy_buffering-off